# JavaScript not being executed onClick

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a webpage where I'm processing an HTML form using JavaScript and onClick, but the JavaScript code isn't being executed.

This is my form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="reportform">
    <input type="radio" name="report" value="customer"><p>Customers</p>
    <input type="radio" name="report" value="item"><p>Items Sold</p>
    <input type="radio" name="report" value="department"><p>Sales Departments</p>
    <input type="radio" name="report" value="person"><p>Sales People</p>
    <input type="button" name="reportsubmit" value="Submit" onClick="checkReport(this.form)">
</form>
```

And this is the JavaScript code (by this way both the JavaScript and the form are located in the body tag):

```
function checkReport (form) 
{
    var checked = form.querySelector('input:checked');
    var value = checked ? checked.value : null;

    if (value == "customer") 
    {
        var href = "http://bdpastudents.com/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php";
        var idx = href.indexOf("Reports", 0);
        var new_href = href.slice(0,idx+19) + "#customer" + href.slice(idx+19);

        window.location.replace(new_href);
    } 
    else if (value == "item") 
    {
        var href = "http://bdpastudents.com/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php";
        var idx = href.indexOf("Reports", 0);
        var new_href = href.slice(0,idx+19) + "#item" + href.slice(idx+19);

        window.location.replace(new_href);
    } 
    else if (value == "department") 
    {
        var href = "http://bdpastudents.com/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php";
        var idx = href.indexOf("Reports", 0);
        var new_href = href.slice(0,idx+19) + "#department" + href.slice(idx+19);

        window.location.replace(new_href);
    } 
    else if (value == "person") 
    {
        var href = "http://bdpastudents.com/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php";
        var idx = href.indexOf("Reports", 0);
        var new_href = href.slice(0,idx+19) + "#person" + href.slice(idx+19);

        window.location.replace(new_href);
    }
}

function checkCustomer(form) 
{
    var checked = form.querySelector('input:checked');
    var value = checked ? checked.value : null;

    if (value == "all") 
    {
        var href = "http://bdpastudents.com/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php";
        var idx = href.indexOf("Reports", 0);
        var new_href = href.slice(0,idx+19) + "#allcustomers" + href.slice(idx+19);

        window.location.replace(new_href);
    } 
    else if (value == "one") 
    {
        var href = "http://bdpastudents.com/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php";
        var idx = href.indexOf("Reports", 0);
        var new_href = href.slice(0,idx+19) + "#onecustomer" + href.slice(idx+19);

        window.location.replace(new_href);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is supposed to happen when you have two functions with the exact same name ?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to use the `onSubmit` event on the `<form>` element instead

Comment: I skipped over that. Sorry I have to rename the second function. Thanks!

Comment: I changed it. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried changing your onclick into `onclick="checkReport(this.form); return false;"`? In my browser it runs just fine, but I don't know what the policy is when the window.location is changed during form-submit

Comment: I found the problem but it is very odd. If I take out the link to my CSS file, then it works. Why would that be?

Comment: Can you show us the link to the CSS file?

Answer (score -1):

<del>Your HTML is illegal. You have not closed your input tags.</del>  Who knew, you don't have to close your tags. Sorry about that.

Can you replicate your problem on this fiddle? Or does this work for you?

```
var form = document.getElementById('reportForm');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mgDGN/

Comment: What am I supposed to do with the form variable? And you don't have to close your input tags

Comment: input is a void-element and doesn't need to be closed (unless the doctype is XHTML, and even then the browser will most likely still accept it).

Comment: That's great but how do I get my javascript to execute?

Comment: Can you not use the form variable? I couldn't get your problem to replicate. What errors are you getting when you debug?